# Strange behavior with a Javascript array, object and RaphaelJS

Tags: javascript, raphael, graphael

I have a situation of defining an object with an array in it. For some reason Chrome adds artifacts to that object before I try to use it.

My Object:

```
var colorPalettes = {
            single_A7DBD8: {
                amounts: [100],
                colors: ['#A7DBD8']
            }, 
            single_C02942: {
                amounts: [100],
                colors: ['#C02942']
            }
}
```

When I run the code, the console shows the following content for `var colorPalettes`:

```
amounts: Array[1]
   0: Object  //<-- added by Chrome, 'value' should come directly in the array
     order: 0
     value: 100
     valueOf: function (){return this.value}
     __proto__: Object
     length: 1
     __proto__: Array[0]
colors: Array[1]
   0: "#A7DBD8"
     length: 1
    __proto__: Array[0]
    __proto__: Object
```

**The questions are:**

1. Why does `amounts` have an `Object` inside the array? - I didn't define it.
2. If so - why isn't `colors` demonstrating the same behavior?
3. Why is this behavior not demonstrated in my code when I run it through jsfiddle?

**What did I try:**

1. In my code `colorPalettes` is set as `window.something.colorPalettes`. I turned it into a local variable - no success.
2. I tried swapping the order of `amounts` and `colors` (I know, I was desperate...) - so the behavior also swapped, now `colors` had the extra `Object`.
3. I put my code into http://jsfiddle.net/2JfyX/4/ but the behavior was normal - no extra `Object` inside `colorPalettes`.

**Edit 1:**

I also tried to put a string inside `amounts` instead of its current `int`.

**Edit 2:** 

Tried to simulate adding a jQuery click event as in my code, was not able to reproduce http://jsfiddle.net/2JfyX/19/

**Edit 3:** 

I believe I have found the culprit. It is g.Raphael. For some reason (didn't delve into their code yet), it makes changes to the object I pass to it

You can see that I directly pass `colorPalettes` to r.piechart and in the 6th loop it changes my array to contain an object. Not nice :-O

I will clone the arrays from now on and hope for the best...

```
function renderPalettes(colorPalettes, radius) {

            var gap = radius + 20;

            for (var palette in colorPalettes) {

                var paletteObj = r.piechart(gap, 43, radius, colorPalettes[palette].amounts, {
                    colors: colorPalettes[palette].colors,
                    stroke: "#cdcdcd",
                    strokewidth: '0.3'
                });

                for (var i = 0; i < paletteObj.series.items.length; i++) {

                    paletteObj.series.items[i].node.setAttribute('class', palette + ' sliderPalette');



                }

                gap = gap + radius * 2 + 24;
            }
        }
```

Any idea? Thanks,
D.

Comment: Console.log your colorTest and you will see the [`__proto__`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/proto) object in jsFiddle too

Comment: In Javascript, arrays are a type of object.

Comment: It is not the same for colors because you instantiate the first item in the array with a string value.

Comment: @mplungjan: I am not talking about __proto__ - I am talking about defining `amounts` as an array and getting some kind of Object in it and `value` is inside this object.

Comment: @crad: I forgot to mention that I also tried to change `amounts` to be a string - this also changed nothing.

Comment: @Barmar: arrays are a type of an Object but why is the array `amounts` behaving differently from the other array `colors`?

Comment: I don't see this when I enter the assignment in the Chrome console. What do I have to do to reproduce what you're seeing?

Comment: @Barmar: I think I am on to something. In one case I am calling `colorPalettes` in a function - there I have no problem, in the problematic case I am calling `colorPalettes` from within a jQuery function `$(".sliderPalette").on("click", function(e) {

                funcThatCalls_colorPalettes();
            });` There I get the problem. I guess jQuery is doing something to it.

Comment: What do you mean "calling colorPalettes"? Why don't you post your code?

Comment: I suspect that it is because the first is a Number object what you are seeing is the property value and accessor valueOf of that instance. It is not adding an extra object. The value of that number object is 100.

Comment: @Barmar: I go from the light to the heavy, I didn't post all of my code to try and keep this post as short as possible. With my new insight I will try to reproduce on jsfiddle and update my post

Answer (score 0):

I just ran this code in FireFox Firebug. I did console.log() on the object and the following result was displayed.

[image]

This pretty much explains the whole situation. The object has two nested objects inside it **single_A7DBD8** and **single_C02942** Both these objects contain two arrays. "amounts" and "colors".

As you can see the + sign with each array. It shows that these contain elements and we can expand these to see elements at each index of the array.

So if you want to access the first element of amounts array in first object execute this code:

```
console.log(colorPalettes.single_A7DBD8.amounts[0]);
```

**Remember colorPalettes  contains two objects**

Comment: thanks for your reply. I think I have found the reason for this issue - please read my last post.

Comment: Ya sure. Just for what its worth, this answer will help you a long way. Using FireBug you can easily see the state of your objects and scripts and this will save you a lot of time. Happy JavaScripting :D